# how to compare control name to text value

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to loop through all controls and assign a text_changed handler on all textboxes aside from two but the following code does not work it keeps getting inside the if and assigning the handler to these textboxes. Using IsNot in replacement of <> does not work either

```
  Dim textboxes = Me.GetAllControls(Me).OfType(Of TextBox)().Where(Function(x) x.Enabled = True).ToList()
        For Each item As TextBox In textboxes
            If item.Name <> "txtSearchName" AndAlso item.Name <> "txtSearchEmpNum" Then
                Dim TextBox As TextBox = DirectCast(item, TextBox)
                AddHandler TextBox.TextChanged, AddressOf TextBoxTextChanged_Handler
                MsgBox(item.Name & " Has textchanged event handler")
            End If
        Next

Dim textboxes = Me.GetAllControls(Me).OfType(Of TextBox)().Where(Function(x) x.Enabled = True).ToList()
 Private Function GetAllControls(control As Control) As IEnumerable(Of Control)
        'This function gets all controls of specified type
        Dim controls = control.Controls.Cast(Of Control)()
        Return controls.SelectMany(Function(ctrl) GetAllControls(ctrl)).Concat(controls)
    End Function
```

Comment: Assuming the names are correct: `If Control.Name <> "txtSearchName" AndAlso Control.Name <> "txtSearchEmpNum" Then...`

Comment: I've tried this way aswell but I get a weird behaviour I'm debugging right now. When I use AndAlso, it wont get inside that If and assign the handler to any of the textboxes but I'm going through now to see why...

Comment: putting a 'MsgBox(Control.Name & "Has the textchanged handler now")' inside this if statement and nothing hits this

Comment: MsgBox is not a debug tool.  Set a breakpoint and *see* what the Name values are and why it fails.  Using Type names as variables (Control, TextBox) is a bad idea too

Comment: I was going through debugging with breakpoints :p I just thought I'd also put a MsgBox in there for a second 'check' :D

Comment: are the controls on the form itself or in some other container like a GroupBox, Panel, Tagpage etc?  If so, they wont be in the Form's controls collection, but that container's

Comment: they are inside a tabcontrol but I have a function that gets all the controls on the form regardless of where they are. I'll post that in the question so comment isnt flooded

Comment: the loop is *only* looking at the forms controls: `For Each Control As Control In Me.Controls`

Comment: Updated using the grab all controls from the form regardless of container

Comment: Next time, post the real code you have a question about at the outset.

Comment: yeah... I fixed it and have it working now even though I exhausted all options before asking on here.. now I feel dumb , sorry to waste your time though you did help me see what was going on